# jquery getJSON() response empty from cakephp controller, but 200 success

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, cakephp

I can pass my errors from standard http://, but I cannot get the $errors values to render (or even pass) in my jquery call. Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I've been at this for about 5 hours and falling asleep on my face.. Thanks for any guidance and critique.

My jQuery:

```
$j("#applicant_age").focusin(function(){
    $j(this).css("background-color","#FFFFCC");
  });
  $j("#applicant_age").focusout(function(){
    $j(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
    $j.getJSON('<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'plans', 'action'=>'ajax_search_validate'))?>', function(json){
    });
  });
```

Controller Action:

```
function ajax_search_validate() {
    if ($this->Plan->validates()) {
        $this->Plan->set($this->data);
        $errors = $this->Plan->invalidFields();
        $this->set('errors', $errors);
    }
}
```

View (probably pointless to post this but what the hey...):

```
<?php
foreach ($errors as $error) :
?>

<p id="errorStyle" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #FF3333; color: #ffffff; margin:     0px 0px 10px 0px; "><?php echo $error; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

FireBug response:

```
ResponseHeaders
Date    Wed, 18 May 2011 09:28:51 GMT
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny10
P3P CP="N..."
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Server  Apache/2.2.9 .....
Content-Type    text/html
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
RequestHeaders
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

The view you are rendering is HTML, so your `$.getJSON` call is fetching a bunch of HTML, and not JSON. The response will appear empty if the JSON does not validate, which is why you are seeing nothing returned in your `$.getJSON` call (despite the 200 success response). Try this:

```
$j.get('<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'plans', 'action'=>'ajax_search_validate'))?>', function(html){
    alert(html);
});
```

If you really do want JSON to be returned to the client, you will need to modify your controller to return some. Something like:

```
echo json_encode(array('errors', $errors));
```

You will probably have to disable the default view rendering behaviour (or create a JSON view). I am not familiar with CakePHP so I can't really go into the details as to how that can be achieved.